# Check for not required property existing in mongoose model variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

So, I have this mongoose scheemas structure:

```
const execStatusScheema = new mongoose.Schema(...)

const notifyScheema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  sms: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  smsStatus: {
    type: execStatusScheema
  },
  telegram: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  telegramStatus: {
    type: execStatusScheema
  },
  voice: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  voiceStatus: {
    type: execStatusScheema
  }
})

const Notify = mongoose.model('Notify', notifyScheema)
module.exports.Notify = Notify
```

as you can see in Notify scheema smsStatus, voiceStatus and telegramStatus are not required. If sms is false, the smsStatus property is not assiged in my code, and for voice and telegram the same behavior. I want to check in Notify some of these propertys. I do the follow:

```
    const uncomplitedNotifies = await Notify.find(...).select('smsStatus voiceStatus telegramStatus sms voice telegram') 
  uncomplitedNotifies.forEach(async notify => {
    console.log(notify)

    if ('telegramStatus' in notify) {
      console.log('123')
    }
...
```

Result is:

```
{ _id: 5ba07aaa1f9dbf732d6cbcdb,
  priority: 5,
  sms: true,
  telegram: false,
  voice: false,
  smsStatus: 
   { status: 'run',
     _id: 5ba07aaa1f9dbf732d6cbcdc,
     errMessage: 'Authentication failed',
     statusDate: '2018-9-18 12:10:19' } }
123
```

Ok, I find one, and its ok, but my if statment is true even I have no this property in my object. I guess it check in scheema object, where its declared, but I want to check in my 'real' object I got by query.
I also try this checking case, but the same result:

```
if (typeof something === "undefined") {
    alert("something is undefined");
}
```

How can I check this object correctly ?

Comment: So if you type `if (typeof notify.telegramStatus === 'undefined') console.log('yes')` can you or can you not see `yes` in the console?

Comment: Oh, this works. I can see 'yes', so its undefined. Maybe I make some mistake when trying by my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator checks the object's own properties and its prototype chain. The unset properties are in the prototype chain of your object, but not on the object's own properties:

```
  const hasTelegramStatus = 'telegramStatus' in document; // true
  const hasTelegramStatus = document.hasOwnProperty('telegramStatus') // false
```

One option is to convert the query into an object by doing `document.toObject()`, which will remove the prototype chain and only return the own properties.